# can't use Session()->get('') in laravel 6.x (6.9.0)

Tags: laravel, session, view

this code is work fine in laravel 5.8:

Controller:

```
return View::make('rev.index')->with('alert-danger','test message');
```

index blade:

```
@if(Session()->has('alert-danger'))
<p class="alert alert-danger">{{ Session()->get('alert-danger') }} </p>
@endif
```

but in lravael 6.x above code is not working(without any error)

Comment: If you want to use the global helper, it's in lowercase : `session()->get('alert-danger');`, or use the static version in capitalize : `Session::get('alert-danger');`

Comment: thanks fir your reply but It's not worked

Comment: Ah I missreaded, when you use `with` when you create a view, the data doesn't go in session, but as a classic variable. You can access in your view `@if ($alert-danger)...`

Comment: @VincentDecaux tnx again, yes i can access to variable with $alert-danger but in laravel 5.8 i can access with session

Comment: I want to know that must I have use `Session::flash('alert-danger','something')` ??

Comment: May I see your route? I thought there wasbupdate about sessions and route

Answer (score 0):

for get session value use:

```
<pre>
    {{ session('alert-danger') }}
</pre>
```